# I need help finding a way to have an accurate count of MongoDB array

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to solve some logic to iterate the correct page using iron router and the _id from the MongoDB.

So far, so good. Everything is working fine in the code below except the last part:

```
   Template.question.events({
  "click .button": function(e){
    e.preventDefault;

    var init ="";

    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("choices").length; i++){

      if (document.getElementsByName("choices")[i].checked){
        init = document.getElementsByName("choices")[i].value;
      }
    }

    var id = "";

    var currentId = this._id;
  Answers.insert({answer: init}, function(error, result){
        if (error){
          console.log("error: " + error);
        } else if (result){
          id = result;

          var solution = Answers.findOne({_id: id}, {answer: 1});
          var quizSubmission = Quiz.findOne({_id: currentId},{answer:1});


          if(solution.answer === quizSubmission.answer){
              counter++;
          }
        }

      });

      console.log(this._id);

      var queue = Quiz.find().fetch();
      compare.unshift(this._id);

      for(var i = 0; i < queue.length; i++){

        if(! _.contains(compare, queue[i]._id)){
        result = queue[i]._id;
      } else if (queue.length === 0){
        console.log("Loading scores...");
      }
      }
      console.log(compare);

      Router.go("question", {_id: result});
  }

});
```

The last part, which is the `else if (queue.length === 0)` portion, is giving me trouble because after every single event handler iteration, the fetch().find() method I call from my MongoDB is reset to the original number of items, instead of ideally having one less item than the previous iteration.

My question is, is there any way to give the length of the MongoDB array without it resetting to 0? Maybe a way to make a temporary copy of the Database.find().fetch() array? I hope what I'm asking makes sense.

Comment: Can you change your `Quiz.find()` query to simply exclude already completed items? Does your model support that? If not, it should. You're randomizing questions right? And then selecting from the not-yet-completed ones?

Comment: @MichelFloyd I'll look into that. Yeah, the questions are randomized, while I push the current question's id into an empty array, which holds all the questions that are answered. I'll look into integrating it into the find query. Thanks for your reply.